# Photon PUN: Is it possible to receive event when custom room properties have been changed?

Tags: photon

When using Photon Unity Networking (PUN), can I receive an event on all clients when some custom room property has been changed by one of the clients (for example by calling **PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties()** )?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Photon event but OnPhotonCustomRoomPropertiesChanged Unity message fired each time custom room properties updated.
You can find more such messages and details on its usage in \Assets\Photon Unity Networking\Plugins\PhotonNetwork\Enums.cs

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much! Should have checked PunBehaviour callback methods!